# Chart.js - Override inherited colors when coloring graphs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm creating graphs with ChartJS, but they seem to inherit the default colors of some parent element. The graphs look like this:
[image]

I am dynamically creating the charts, depending on selections from the user. The ChartJS chart takes in an array of either primitives, or objects to use as the chart data. I'm using the following function to create the chart objects, and then using an array of these objects as the parameter for ChartJS:

```
function getChartDataObject(data){
    var title = data['metadata']['title'];
    var color = random_rgba();
    console.log(`Color: ${color}`);
    var dataObject = {
        label: title,
        data: data['scaled_interval'],
        color: color,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        radius: 1,
    }
    return dataObject;
}
```

Then I create the master chart with this function:

```
function createIntervalChart(intervalDataObjects, datetimeInterval) {
    const cnvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = $(cnvs);

    var data = {
        labels: datetimeInterval,
        datasets: intervalDataObjects,
    }

    var options = {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: "top",
            text: "Projected Load Profiles",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontColor: "#111",
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "bottom",
            labels: {
                fontColor: "#333",
                fontSize: 16
            }
        },
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 0
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            zoom: {
                zoom: {
                    wheel: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    pinch: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    mode: 'xy',
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Estimated Load Profiles"
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: data,
        options: options
    });

    return cnvs;
}
```

When I check the console, I see distinct colors created by the `random_rgb()` function, but they all turn out grey.

```
Color: rgba(215,231,183,0.6)
Color: rgba(253,61,199,0.1)
Color: rgba(27,15,88,0.1)
```

Does anyone know how to create a ChartJS chart with custom colors? Or how to override inherited styling for these charts? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` is not a valid `dataset` property for a line chart. Use `borderColor` and optionally also `backgroundColor` (will be used for drawing the legend label box).

```
function getChartDataObject(data){
    var title = data['metadata']['title'];
    var color = random_rgba();
    console.log(`Color: ${color}`);
    var dataObject = {
        label: title,
        data: data['scaled_interval'],
        borderColor: color, // <- to be changed
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        radius: 1,
    }
    return dataObject;
}
```

> For further information, please consult [Dataset Properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) from the Chart.js documentation.